# Intents, bundles

Tags: android

Mi pregunta es la siguiente como se puede hacer para mandar imagenes en intents usando bundles. Un ejemplo seria tengo una actividad en la cual al presionar un Imagebutton pasa a la siguiente en la cual quiero que me ponga la imagen que tenia el button. Pero en lugar de un solo boton tengo 4 en una acitvidad.

```
public void btn_hombre(View view) {

    if (hombre.isChecked() == true && hombre_bajo.isClickable()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(GeneroActivity.this,holaActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("hombre_alto", R.drawable.hombre_alto);
        startActivity(intent);

    }else if (hombre_normal.isClickable()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(GeneroActivity.this, IMCActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("hombre_pequeño", R.drawable.hombre_pequeño);
        startActivity(intent);

    }else if (hombre_sobrepeso.isClickable()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(GeneroActivity.this, IMCActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("hombre_sobrepeso", R.drawable.hombre_sobrepeso);
        startActivity(intent);

    }else if (hombre_sobrepeso1.isClickable()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(GeneroActivity.this, IMCActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("hombre_sobrepeso1", R.drawable.hombre_sobrepeso1);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

algo asi mando a la segunda actividad.

el detalle esque no se como recibirlo en la segunda actividad para activar un condicional para poder mostrar la imagen correspondiente en el imageview. segun seleccione. Gracias de ante mano por la ayuda.

Comment: Con lo que haces le estás pasando la referencia al objeto imagen que declaras en el xml, no podrías pasar la ruta de la imagen y cargarla en la nueva actividad? Para diferenciar qué botón estás pulsando podrías añadir al intent un entero (por ejemplo) para diferenciar que botón has pulsado

Comment: Puedes leer [tour] y [ask] para aprender como funciona el sitio y además ganarás tu primera medalla!

Answer (score 0):

La imagen está en tu proyecto, no necesitas pasar la imagen, sólo una referencia a ella para saber cuál es.

```
public void btn_hombre(View view) {
    String imgsel;
    if (hombre.isChecked() == true && hombre_bajo.isClickable()) {
        imgsel = "hombre_alto";
    }else if (hombre_normal.isClickable()) {
        imgsel = "hombre_pequeño";
    }else if (hombre_sobrepeso.isClickable()) {
        imgsel = "hombre_sobrepeso";
    }else if (hombre_sobrepeso1.isClickable()) {
        imgsel = "hombre_sobrepeso1";
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(GeneroActivity.this,holaActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("btnselect", imgsel);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Y en el destino del intent recoges el bundle, donde ya tienes el nombre de la imagen. A partir del nombre identificas la imagen y la asocias al ImageView donde quieres mostrarla.

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras(); 
String imagen = bundle.getString("btnselect");
```